# RewriteRule allow access to only certain subfolders in a folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following structure

```
index.php
.htaccess
system
 - config
 - classes
 - modules
   - module_name
     - js
     - css
```

My goal is to disable direct access to whole "system" folder excluding asset folders "js" and "css"

How to do that properly using `RewriteRule` in the root .htaccess?

Currently I figured out how to disable "system" directory using `RewriteRule ^system/ - [F]`
It works fine but also disables my assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your more specific *exceptions* before your block-all rule. For example, try the following:

```
# Exceptions: Don't block these URLs
RewriteRule ^system/modules/module_name/(js|css)/ - [L]

# Block the rest...
RewriteRule ^system/ - [F]
```

The preceding *exceptions* simply prevent any further rewriting when URLs of this format are requested.

**UPDATE:** If the `modules` and `modules_name` directories are variable then you can change this to:

```
RewriteRule ^system/\w+/\w+/(js|css)/ - [L]
```

`\w` being the shorthand character class for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: There is unknown number of modules. I must disable everything but "js" and "css" folders.

Comment: Thanks, it works and solution is pretty simple, need to learn regexp better :)